# Is it possible to use Synergy KVM over LTE / hotspot networks?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ip, lan, kvm-switch

Synergy is a software KVM solution that afaik uses IP/TCP sockets to broadcast peripheral usage between pc's.

My strange use case is that I bet (on e-sports) across multiple mini-pc's which are all connected to separate wireless T-Mobile hotspot devices, obviously because I'm not supposed to use more than one account per person/ per household.

Ideally, I wouldn't need 4x peripherals, and Synergy has the ability to display and seamlessly mouse between all 4 on one screen.

Question is: how do I get all these mini pc's on the same "network" without the outbound connection ever being from the same IP address? My guess is stringing together some routers that have SIM card functionality to create a LAN internet for the Synergy app to work, while somehow making all web-requests remain over their respective cellular network?

Honestly no idea, and I'd really appreciate a nudge in the right direction. Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If those mini-PCs have LAN ports you can just purchase a cheap 5-port switch.

Then you can configure the miniPCs with static IPs in the same range and plug them to the switch. The only thing needed is the IP and subnet mask. Note that the IP addresses must be on a different range from the Wi-Fi adapters; so if Wi-Fi addresses are for example 192.168.1.x, configure LAN adapters with 192.168.2.x 255.255.255.0.

As long as you don't change the default gateways (and don't configure new ones to the wired interfaces) they will communicate to the internet using the hotspots, and with each other over the LAN port. If they don't have LAN ports but have USB ports, you can get USB-to-ethernet adapters and do the same. USB-Eth adapters may require installing drivers.

If you don't want to add cabling, the same could be done by adding a second Wi-Fi adapter. The principle is still the same, but in practice it gets a bit more complicated.

Comment: this sounds like a perfectly simple solution for somebody w/ little experience in networking. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yeah, the only know-how needed is how to plug in cables and give IP addresses :-D You're welcome :-)

Comment: Had to update - forgot one important little bit of info...

Comment: I can probably figure that out :P. I wouldn't even need to plug the switch into a router correct? So the "5th port" wouldn't be used? I may comment on this in the future I would be happy to pay u via BTC when the time comes that I may need a little help.

Comment: Nice timing :-D No, the 5th port can stay empty. And you neither need nor should add a router to the soup; routers forward traffic between networks, while routers operate within one subnet. Payment's neither necessary nor would me accepting one be appreciated by the community :-) I had to complete the answer for it to be helpful for someone else with similar question but less know-how.

Comment: ur a legend man. Thank you a million times over... i've been wondering about this for ages as I stare at my 4 mice and keyboards lol

Comment: would I be able to accomplish this on an unmanaged switch / plug n play switch? such as https://www.bestbuy.com/site/netgear-5-port-10-100-1000-mbps-gigabit-unmanaged-switch-white/6840341.p?skuId=6840341

Comment: Yap. As long as addressing's done right it's pretty much set-and-forget :)